# Highcharts Export PDF - for Dynamically inserted series

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, highcharts

I have dynamically inserted series for highcharts, I have been trying to export the chart to PDF like the following.

fiddle example :
http://jsfiddle.net/jq0zbffb/

Updated code :

```
// getMyChart() starts 

function getMyChart() {
    var myChart;
    Highcharts.setOptions({
                    lang: {
                        thousandsSep: ',',
                         numericSymbols: ['M']
                    }
                });

    var options = {
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'container',
            type : 'area'
            },

        xAxis : {
            lineWidth: 0,
            categories : []
        },

        yAxis : [ {
                    title : {
                        text : 'Averages',
                    },

                    lineWidth: 0,
                    } ,
                    {
                    title : {
                        text : 'Values',
                    },

                    opposite: true,
                    lineWidth: 0,

                }],
         series : []
  };

        // jQuery 

        $.get(url, function(xml) {
            var $xml = $(xml);
            $xml.find('categories Date').each(
                        function(i, category) {
                            options.xAxis.categories.push($(category).text());
                        });


            $xml.find('type Series').each(
                        function(i, series) {
                            var seriesOptions = {
                                name : $(series).find('name').text(),
                                data : []

                                };
                                $(series).find('data point').each(
                                    function(i, point) {
                                        seriesOptions.data.push(parseInt($(point).text()));
                                        });
                                options.series.push(seriesOptions);
                            });

            myChart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
    //jquery ends

    //  .getSVG function 

       Highcharts.getSVG = function(charts) {

            var svgArr = [],
            top = 0,
            width = 0;

        $.each(charts, function(i, chart) {
            var svg = chart.getSVG();
            svg = svg.replace('<svg', '<svg transform="translate(0,' + top + ')" ');
            svg = svg.replace('</svg>', '</svg>');

            top += chart.chartHeight;
            width = Math.max(width, chart.chartWidth);

            svgArr.push(svg);
        });

        console.log(svgArr);
        return '<svg height="'+ top +'" width="' + width + '" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + svgArr.join('') + '</svg>';
    };
    Highcharts.exportCharts = function(charts, options) {

        options = Highcharts.merge(Highcharts.getOptions().exporting, options);

        Highcharts.post(options.url, {
            filename: options.filename || 'Pulse_Chart',
            type: options.type,
            width: options.width,
            svg: Highcharts.getSVG(charts)
        });
    };

    $('#export').click(function() {
        Highcharts.exportCharts([myChart], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    });

    } // getMyCharts ends
```

HTML :

```
<div id="container" class="myChart" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    <button id="export">Export all</button>
```

Issue :

```
SCRIPT5009: 'chart' is undefined
```

I use jQuery to dynamically insert series.

Is there a possibility to export charts like this? Can anyone please point out where am i going wrong?
Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: For Highcharts it doesn't matter how you load series (on init or using `addSeries()`) - current chart is exported as PDF. What kind of issues you have? Maybe it's better to post your actual code, not the one works.

Comment: @PawełFus I have posted my actual code here. Can you please tell what should be done?

Comment: And you see, `chart` is undefined because you define chart in the local scope here: `var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);`. In fact you should define chart at the beginning of your code: `var chart;` and then use `chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);`.

Comment: Oh Thanks! i corrected it, i get this error `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getSVG' `. i even added this `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>`

Comment: Could you update your code with the changes? It's hard to guess what is wrong :) Maybe try using different variable, not `chart` but `myChart` ?

Comment: i changed `chart` to `myChart` and posted my updated code here! :) Is it clear now? also i get `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'post' ` error.

Comment: That means you didn't include `exporting.js` file. Make sure you load it **after** Highcharts core.

Comment: i have actually used this : `https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"` Is this the correct cdn? i get this once i added the exporting.js -> `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'document': object is null or undefined ` in IE9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108633/discussion-between-disera-and-pawel-fus).

Comment: Is there any correct cdn available for `exporting.js`. Please share it with us. It will be helpful for many. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This is a correct cdn. You can also download files and provide them from your server, just to try things.

Comment: Actually i have tried that too, is it an IE issue? I use IE9

Comment: I don't think so, all jsFiddle demos works fine in IE9 too. Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: Yes, Others like Firefox and chrome works well, but I am in need of exporting highcharts to PDF using IE9 :( . The thing is, IE9 is not accepting some cdns & downloaded files. Is there any other way at all to export highchart to PDF? Any idea is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: My IE9 works fine, so maybe you configured something strange in IE9? I've never heard before that Highcharts CDN is blocked. Also, if CDN is blocked, then use files from your server. Do you have the same issues in IE9 testing for example [this demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic)?

Comment: In the above code, i get error in this line `var svg = chart.getSVG();` stating that `Object doesn't support property or method 'getSVG' ` can you please tell me why is that? From where should the method getSVG() refer to?

Comment: Sorry for a late response. Please update your code accordingly to your changes. Make sure it's 1:1 in the question. What do you have in `console.log(chart)` before that line?

Comment: Pawel Fus I have the updated code here, and console.log(chart) is present before the return statement. it renders to  `<svg transform="translate(0,0)"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="font-family: 'lucida grande', .........  transform="translate(0,20)" x="8" ></text></g></svg> ` after this the page stays the same. I do not get any message or alert for pdf. I dont know where i am going wrong. any suggestions please. Thanks

Comment: Ok, you made some changes to the original case here: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/gd7bB/ - all of them are reasons why you can not get what you want. For example now, you have `<svg>` instead of `<g>`. And this: `svg = svg.replace('</svg>', '</svg>');` ? Why it's changed.

Comment: Actually i have tried using `<g>`, i get the same issue. Actually the scenario works and pdf is getting generated, when chart is defined like this `var myChart = new Highcharts.Chart({....});` as it is done in the above fiddle. When it is defined like this: `var options = { chart:{....}};`  and created in jquery  ` $.get(url, function(xml) {...... var myChart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); });` it doesn't create a pdf.  I am not sure, but i think the problem is with the chart definition. Please tell me if am wrong anywhere?

Comment: Define `var myChart;` at the very beginning of the script. Make it as global variable, so all methods later can pick proper chart. If you define a variable inside function, then scope in JS will block you and you will get error like in the very beginning.

Comment: I tried what you said, chart is not getting exported :( Do you think is it  because of the chart definition like i said in the previous comment?

Comment: Chart definition doesn't matter. I mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gd7bB/2481/ (first define variables, then create chart, note missing `var` when creating chart). Please, provide more detailed description, simple `doesn't work` won't help me to help you :( Error message at least, please.

Comment: @Pawel Fus Sorry! i have a sample fiddle which explains my scenario. http://jsfiddle.net/bd0m7ucL/  Can you help me from this?

Comment: @PawełFus Are you able to recreate my problem in IE9 or Firefox, using the above fiddle? Please suggest an idea

Comment: @Disrea : where is `exporting.js` file in your demo? It's missing and that's the reason nothing works for you. See fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bd0m7ucL/1/

Comment: @PawełFus Thank you! This works well in Firefox and chrome, but in IE9 i get `Unable to get value of the property 'getSVG': object is null or undefined` error. Is it solved for you in IE9?

Comment: @PawelFus, the above fixed demo fiddle doesn't seem to work in IE9. i have checked in IE11 and other browsers, where it works fine.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work because you have errors in the console? It looks like `$.get()` doesn't work in IE9, so I don't think it's an issue with Highcharts..